# Ubuntu server is not booting using the custom image option

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install ubuntu server on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I used the Raspberry Pi imager with the image `Other general purpose OS > Ubuntu > Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS`.

But it turns out that this image is a modified image of the ubuntu server image.
When I use `uname -r` I get `5.4.3-1028-raspi` which is not the kernel shipped with a classic ubuntu server.

So I wanted to use the official image of [Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) (the arm version).
I tried installing it on my SD card with the Raspberry Pi imager as pointed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) using the `Custom Image` option.

But when I do that, the Raspberry Pi does not boot.

The screen says that the SD card is detected, it says `Partition: 0` and retry to boot every 20 seconds.
How could I make the Ubuntu Server image boot ?

Answer (score 1):

Though the Pi is an ARM processor Ubuntu have classed these boards as [IOT](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot) devices and have a specific build for them that can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

I would download this first then use the software to create the SD card image.

Edit: A list of supported ARM boards is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server/Install)